# How to get an enum value ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, enums

I have a ProjectsModel as a viewmodel:

```
public IEnumerable<TheProjects> OurProjects { get; set; }

public class TheProjects
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public short PhaseCount { get; set; }
    public string ProjectOwner { get; set; }
    public byte Priority { get; set; }
}
```

And I have Project as a model:

```
public enum PriorityForProject
{
    Acil = 0,
    Normal = 1,
    Düsük = 2
}

namespace JobTracking.Models
{
    public class Project
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public int ProjectNo { get; set; }
        public string ProjectType { get; set; }
        public string ProjectOwner { get; set; }
        public string StartDate { get; set; }
        public string EndDate { get; set; }
        public string ProjectManager { get; set; }
        public string Team { get; set; }
        public string ProjectDescription { get; set; }
        public PriorityForProject Priority { get; set; }
        public string Costs { get; set; }
        public string CashExpenditures { get; set; }
        public short Sira { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you see, I have the enum in my project.cs and here is my controller:

```
public ActionResult Index(int S = 1)
{
    var itemsPerPage = 100;
    var model = new ProjectsModel
    {
        ItemsPerPage = itemsPerPage,
        Page = S,
        TotalItems = Db.MyProjects.Count(),
        OurProjects = Db.MyProjects.OrderByDescending(o => o.Sira).Skip((S - 1) * itemsPerPage).Take(itemsPerPage)
        .Select(s => new ProjectsModel.TheProjects
        {
            Id = s.Id,
            ProjectName = s.ProjectName,
            PhaseCount = (short)Db.MyPhases.Where(p => p.Project.Id == s.Id).Count(),
            ProjectOwner=s.ProjectOwner,
            Priority = (byte)s.Priority
        })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

I am trying to get PriorityForProject method's value. From the controller, as you see, I can get the byte type which returns a number. How can I reach the value of it ?

Comment: Why are you using `byte` for the `TheProjects.Priority` property, when the underlying type of `PriorityForProject` is `int`? It would be cleaner if they were the same.

Comment: yes I made them all same @JonSkeet thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must cast to the propertyforproject type `(PriorityForProject)`.

If you don't want to bother with values you can declare a PropertyForProject property in your model.

```
public class TheProjects
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProjectName { get; set; }
        public short PhaseCount { get; set; }
        public string ProjectOwner { get; set; }
        public byte PriorityValue { get; set; } /* check if you really need this */
        public PriorityForProject Priority { get; set; }

    }
```

I assume enums are in your core level of application, so there mustn't be a problem with references.

Comment: yes You are right they are just core level of app. So as you said I did  public PriorityForProject Priority { get; set; } thank you so much =)

Answer (score 3):

Just cast:

```
TheProjects x = ...;
PriorityForProject priority = (PriorityForProject) x.Priority;
```

(I'd strongly advise you to rename the `TheProjects` type though - that's a really unwieldy, unidiomatic name...)

Comment: well I am still learning. Why it is unwieldy could you please explain more and lead me to write clear and idiomatic code. Also it worked

Comment: @Jackal: It's the name - `The` is meaningless as part of a name, and `Projects` is odd when it's only a single project. It's not clear why you're got two representations of the `Project` type anyway, to be honest.

Comment: well I called it Projects because user will be added a lot of projects and I called it Projects because if I use Project for model and viewmodel sometimes it creates error because of the same name(I got that a few times).So when I need model I make it unique like PROJECT and for the wiew models I make it like Projects and OurProjects then I can find whatever I need without confusing myself after I look at the code

Comment: @Jackal: If you need to disambiguate, something like `ProjectViewModel` would make a lot more sense. Making it plural when *in itself* it's singular is just confusing (if you have a lot of projects, you'd have a `List<Project>` or whatever - and using `Our`, `The` etc is just unpredictable IMO.

Comment: Yea u are right. But I am only using it because they all should be unique name.I will keep what you say it in my mind. What should I use instead of Our and The ?

Comment: @Jackal: As I said, if you *really* need two types, but this is the view model, then `ProjectViewModel` seems pretty self-explanatory to me.

Comment: yes Thats How I use. Thank you for your time and explanation